# Is there any better way to talk about change(money)?

Tags: word-usage

1. let suppose I have a hundred dollar note but i need 80 dollar dollars out of it.
   So I can ask the grocery person "Can I have change?" 
   Any better way to say so?
2. how to say if i need each note of 10 dollars (total 10notes)
3. and if I have change and i need one or bigger notes how ca i ask ask? As this is not suitable if i say do you need change?

Your views will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: "Would you mind changing a hundred for tens?" "Would you have a hundred for smaller bills?"

Comment: On your last question, you can say something like *can I give you ones for a twenty?* or *can I exchange fifty dollars in smaller bills for a fifty?* or something like that.

Comment: For scenario one (paying with a large bill, wanting particular small bills as change) you might say "can I get $40 of that as ones?" (the "that" is referring to your change, "ones" means one-dollar bills).  Also note that it is rude to try to take most or all of a cashier's most-used currency; taking away 80 or 40 or even 10 one-dollar bills might cause them to run out the next time they need to give 'normal' change.

Comment: May I have my changes in tens. Do you have any tens?